# Is it possible to use system.runas with the force cli?

Tags: unit-test, force-cli

Sometimes when creating UnitTests I'm unable to save classes for hours at a time.
It'd be great - as a workaround - to develop UnitTests using the "force cli".

However, I'm unable to execute code that has system.runas in it.

An "ERROR: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: admin operation already in progress" error occurs.

Is this possible?

```
PS C:\salesforce\dev04> force apex -test
 Start typing Apex code; press CTRL-D(for Mac/Linux) / Ctrl-Z (for Windows) when finished

Test.startTest();
Id foProfile = FO_UnitTest_V2_Helper.getProfileId(FO_UnitTest_V2_Helper.FRONT_OFFICE_PROF_NAME);
User testUser = FO_UnitTest_V2_Helper.createUser(foProfile, 'T', 'User');
insert testUser;
System.runAs(testUser){
    \/\/ code here
}
Test.stopTest();

^Z
```

> Executing code...
> ERROR: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: admin operation already in progress

Answer (score 2):

System.runAs only runs in actual unit tests. Execute Anonymous is not a unit test context; any changes you make in Execute Anonymous successfully will save.

If you want to run tests, you need to do a metadata deployment. If you don't want to actually save the changes, use the `-c` (check only) deployment mode. However, metadata deployments are still always in serial, so you'd still have to wait.

If you're experiencing challenges with deployments taking excessively long, you probably need to start using [Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) or [Sandboxes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.create_test_instance.htm&type=5). This gives you own dedicated developer org to test changes, reducing the number of deployments you'll have to wait on.

You should not have more than one developer deploying to an org because of the limitations around deployments.

Your question appears to be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/); you're trying to solve a congestion problem, and this "solution" is a non-starter. You may want to take a step back and reevaluate what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on its [documentation](https://force-cli.herokuapp.com/), the `force apex` command executes Anonymous Apex, *not* an Apex unit test. The `runAs()` construct, along with `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`, is available only in the context of an Apex unit test.

Note that executing Anonymous Apex also does not save anything - it is not a development activity. The Force CLI is an open source project and is not the official Salesforce CLI.

This error:

> ERROR: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: admin operation already in progress

is linked to your broader problem (below), not to this specific Apex construct.

> Sometimes when creating UnitTests I'm unable to save classes for hours at a time. It'd be great - as a workaround - to develop UnitTests using the "force cli".

The recommended approach to solve this is twofold:

1. Develop your code in *version control*, not in an org. Deploy your code using the official Salesforce CLI (`sfdx`). You can use an IDE or third-party CLI if you wish but it won't fundamentally change the paradigm.
2. Develop in isolated environments - either a scratch org, best of all, or a single-user Developer sandbox. If you are encountering frequent admin locks in the org, that is an indicator that it is being used or deployed against by multiple persons, which is not best practice.

Comment: You can execute Unit tests - that is - execute assert statements - using system.runas like this: \n   Test.startTest(); List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account limit 2];
   System.assertEquals(3, accounts.size(), 'number of accounts');
Test.stopTest();

Comment: Yes, you can do that _in an Apex unit test_. An assertion is not the same thing as a unit test.

Comment: No. You can do that in the force-cli. Copy and try it.

Comment: It's fine if you are able to execute `Test.startTest()` and assertions in Anonymous Apex, but that is not the same thing as writing and saving an Apex unit test to the org. I do not use Force CLI.

Comment: I don't want to save it to the Org. That's the point.

Comment: Then you cannot use `System.runAs()`. See the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) for an explicit statement that what you want is not supported.

Comment: Hi David. The "docs" link you cited is broken: Sorry, the document you are looking for doesn't exist or could not be retrieved. And the force-cli document link your provided is a home page only - not documentation.

Comment: That's a common problem with the Salesforce docs. If you reload the page, it should render. The pertinent line reads "You can use runAs only in test methods. The original system context is started again after all runAs test methods complete."

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately this the documentation you cite has nothing to do with force-cli " . You've never even used force-cli.

Comment: I think that we are talking at cross purposes, Emmett. Force CLI is just an API client like everyone else. It does not have the ability to change how Apex unit tests fundamentally work on the platform, and the documentation is very clear that you can only execute `System.runAs()` in an Apex test method. Running Anonymous Apex is not an Apex test method - I just validated hands-on that you cannot run code annotated with `@isTest` through Anonymous Apex.

Comment: However, the error that you're currently receiving still appears to be part of the root problem that your org is being used and/or deployed against by too many people. If this org is used by you and you alone, you might open a Case with support to determine why it has extended admin locks happening.